# What is the differnce between both the declarations in scala?

Tags: scala

I declared both the variables in two ways. But the output is same as "name". Then what is the difference between both the declarations? Are there any differences in memory allocations?

```
    var x="name"
    println(x)
    var y:String="name"
    println(y)
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `val` by default, instead of `var`. Makes your code easier to reason about when you know you can't change things after it's been constructed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference with respect to memory allocations.

In case 1 Scala compiler infers the type for you

```
var x = "hello"
```

In case 2 You are explicitly announcing the type to guide the compiler

```
var x: String = "hello"
```

Explicit type declaration is important in some cases where Compiler inferred type is not good enough. For example

```
var a = 1
```

Compiler will infer the type of a as Int. But if I want a to be `AnyVal` in this case I have to say `var a: AnyVal = 1`

Comment: Beside the technical part there are some advantages in terms of good code. If you have a call like val x = somefunction(...), you may not see directly which type it is if it's not reasonable by the context.